# Issue while using viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, layoutsubviews

I have heard that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the best place to alter the layout when we have used constraints.

So I jumped to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

I have created three `UIViews` and `SubViewed` them on SuperView. I am not mentioning the code for frame calculation.

```
 [self.view addSubview:imgMiddleCircle];
 [self.view addSubview:imgFirstCircle];
 [self.view addSubview:imgLastCircle];
```

Using this piece of I am adding these circles.

Now when I run my code In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I get following screens:

[image]

And when I switch to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I am getting this on screen:

[image]

Why I am getting extra two circles in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` even I am creating three circles.

And why in `viewWillLayout` gives the correct Output.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times, that's why you see the extra views. So, it is _not_ the best place to add subviews. Typically you'd add the subviews in `viewDidLoad` and if you're really sure that you want to manually calculate the frames, do only that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: you mean Internally `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called multiple times.... And i can't use `viewDidLoad` as I have autolayout turned on. I am doing calculation based on existing controls..and In `viewDidLoad` I am not getting correct frame for existing controls

Comment: @RahulMishra set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and add subviews in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I am creating these views programatically ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should code for the fact that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple types.

Ideally `addSubview:` should be happening in a place like `viewDidLoad` where you are sure it is only called once.

You can create a flag to avoid calling `addSubview:` multiples types (not my personal choice)

Otherwise, try to move your set up code to `viewDidLoad` and force the view to render itself before doing your calculation:

> [yourView setNeedsLayout];
>
> [yourView layoutIfNeeded];

Answer (score 2):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews),

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method. However, this method being called does not indicate that the
>   individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each
>   subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.
>
> Your view controller can override this method to make changes after
>   the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this
>   method does nothing.

So, essentially, `viewDidLayoutSubiews` gets called multiple times during the creation of your viewController including in cases like rotating the device, scrolling etc. So, you should be really careful with the code you add to this method, because it might be executed multiple times as well. **Use this method to reposition your sub-views and not to add/remove them.**

Take a look at this [blog](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/) for more details.

Comment: I want to add a sub layer to my view which has rounded corners. I added the rounded corner code in didLayoutsubviews which makes sense because my elements can change size and I need to adopt the corner radius based on that. Now I added the layer insertion code and because of multiple calls, multiple layers are added, what to do  :(?